# Scroll up and down one section of a page at a time and no more

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created 4 divs and gave them a little css, now when I scroll, it's just a regular scroll, I want to scroll a single section, so that user may not miss any section on the page when scrolling through it, like a section just clips when scrolled down and next section clips on screen when further scrolled down and when going up, backward process happens.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="sections" id="sectionOne">
            <p class="section-text">DIV 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sections" id="sectionTwo">
            <p class="section-text">DIV 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sections" id="sectionThree">
            <p class="section-text">DIV 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sections" id="sectionFour">
            <p class="section-text">DIV 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried the Javascript methods 'onscroll','wheel','scroll','scrollY','deltaY' etc but i can't comprehend the logic writing and stuck on it for days, Help will be appreciated !

I will provide the reference site if anyone contacts me to better communicate the issue, Waiting..

I tried the Buit-in JS EventListeners 'wheel','scroll','scrollY','deltaY' etc...

I am expecting to scroll just one section on scroll down or and one section on scroll up, also expecting it to work on mousepad and apple mouse !

Comment: Take a look at [CSS scroll snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type) it might do exactly what you want

Comment: I did it snaps the next section but it has 2 flaws, we cannot control the speed and if the scroll on mousepad is done a little fast it scrolls more than one section and snaps whichever section is on screen at that time, I want section by section scrolling and not missing a single section when user scrolls.

Comment: The effect is called snap scrolling. You can also have a look at [FullPageJs](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this example. i think solve your problem after using this code:

```js
let currentSection = 0;
    const totalSections = document.querySelectorAll('.sections').length;

    function handleScroll(event) {
      // Normalize wheel delta across different browsers
      const delta = event.wheelDelta || -event.deltaY || -event.detail;

      if (delta > 0 && currentSection > 0) {
        currentSection--;
      } else if (delta < 0 && currentSection < totalSections - 1) {
        currentSection++;
      }

      scrollToSection(currentSection);
    }

    function scrollToSection(sectionIndex) {
      const targetSection = document.querySelectorAll('.sections')[sectionIndex];
      window.scrollTo({
        top: targetSection.offsetTop,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    }

    document.addEventListener('wheel', handleScroll);
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .container {
      height: 400vh; /* Set the height of the container to accommodate all sections */
    }

    .sections {
      height: 100vh; /* Each section takes the full viewport height */
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 2em;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    #sectionOne{background-color: antiquewhite;}
    #sectionTwo{background-color: aquamarine;}
    #sectionThree{background-color: burlywood;}
    #sectionFour{background-color: blanchedalmond;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sections" id="sectionOne">
      <p class="section-text">DIV 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sections" id="sectionTwo">
      <p class="section-text">DIV 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sections" id="sectionThree">
      <p class="section-text">DIV 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sections" id="sectionFour">
      <p class="section-text">DIV 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your code works okay but still if wheel is scrolled a bit fast then the screen scrolls more than one div, i came across fullpage.js and it works great i need to attach that to ODOO site i am working on. Also if there is anything related to mousepad scroll, that would be great

Again, I appreciate your code.

Comment: Thank you so much. Please accept my answer and voteup.